# SQLAlchemy One-To-Many: Constrain Parent to have At Least One Child

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

Suppose I have the simple SQLAlchemy Mapping:

```
class Parent(db.Model)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')

class Child(db.Model)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=False)
    parent = db.relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')
```

In this form it is a **One(Parent)-to-Many(Children)**.

Due to the `nullable` flag every `Child` must have a `Parent` else `IntegrityError` is raised. [Note that the default not to cascade 'deletes' or 'orphan-deletes', ensures when the parent is deleted its children are *not* also deleted, hence the error]

However, I want to raise an `IntegrityError` when a `Parent` has **zero children**.
I.e:

- Creating a new `Parent` without creating and specifying at least one `Child` is prohibited.
- Deleting the last `Child` in a `Parent`s `children` collection is prohibited.

Any way to do this in Postgres (and SQLite 3 in development)?

Answer (score 2):

To make it database agnostic you could use sqlalchemy events to check the parents before insert:

```
from sqlalchemy import event


@event.listens_for(Parent, 'before_insert')
@event.listens_for(Parent, 'before_update')
def receive_before_insert_or_update(mapper, connection, parent):

    if not parent.children:
        # you should probably use your own exception class here
        raise IntegrityError("Parent without children not allowed")
```

This would prevent inserts or updates of a parent with/to not having children. You can use the same pattern with the `before_delete` event to prevent children deletion.

Comment: Does this have any disadvantages? What if the ORM events were missed or not triggered on special events? Whilst I have implemented you solution I still wonder if there is a database configuration that enforces this naturally via some underlying constraints?

Comment: Well I wouldn't expect sqlalchemy to "miss" the events, but you're right in that the database in this way does not really enforce that the parent has a child.